# SQL Wildcard Replace - single character between <br> tag?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a varchar(max) column with HTML present and I need to replace a single character where it is between a line break - `<br></br>` eg: `<br>8</br>`.  The problem is, that character is entirely random so I need the equivalent of a wildcard replace of `<br>%</br>`.  I only need it to happen if it is a single character, not if it is multiple characters.

So if its `<br>#</br>` i want to change it to `<br></br>`

Any ideas how to achieve this?  Function / View / Stored procedure any method will do.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried regex? or replace?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `replace`. Not an expert in SQL server, but it's usually `Replace(texttosearch, paterntofind, newpattern)`

```
Replace(Yourcolumn, '<br>.</br>', '<br></br>')
```

It's unclear if there's other text you want to preserve or not. You may need some capture groups if there is.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this using **[`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188043.aspx)** and **[`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)**

`Charindex` - Helps you identify the position of `<br>`

`Stuff` - Helps you to replace the character with empty string

```
SELECT Stuff(strings, Charindex('<br>', strings) + 4, 1, '') as Result
FROM   (VALUES ('<br>8</br>'),
               ('<br>.</br>'),
               ('<br>#</br>'),
               ('<br>$</br>')) tc (strings)
```

**Result:**

```
Result
------
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
```

Comment: @SkipFeeney - Can `<br></br>` appear in the input? If so, then this will still delete a character and result in `<br>/br>`.

Comment: If such data exist then we handle it through CASE statement